# Jquery ajax function working fine with version 1.8.3-min but not with last version 3.2.1

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this simple function that is working fine with jquery version 1.8.3-min but is not working with the last version 3.2.1 not minified.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'js/js.php',
        type:'POST',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
                $('body').append(data);
            }
        }
    }); 
})
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You should describe how the actual result differs from the expected result.

Comment: This is the html working with jquery-min-183.js - is loading inside the html page a javascript written inside the page js/js.php   
<!-- jQuery Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.183.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
 $.ajax({
  url: 'js/js.php',
  type:'POST',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
   if(data){
    $('body').append(data);
   }
  }
 }); 
})
</script>
</head>


<body>
 
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(window).load(function)` is deprecated and was removed in version 3

Change

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

To

```
$(function() { // shorthand for `$(document).ready()
```

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(document).ready (function (){ 
   //ajax
});
```